# f# one list to another?

Tags: f#

I have a list of tuples with three values in tuples

I want to create new List of strings out of previous list with one value out of tuples.

```
List [(string * string * int) ]

List[ for i in columns -> i.getfirstvalueintuple]
```

How can i do that? very basic question but i can't figure it out.

Also is there any other way of building another kind of list or seq out of existing list?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
seq { for (first, _, _) in lst do yield first };;
```

This gives a sequence. You can also use `List.map`:

```
lst |> List.map (fun (first, _, _) -> first);;
```

Which gives a list.

Comment: Thanks it works great
Also can you please describe what ;; does at the end of list.map statement. Tried to find reference in msdn but can't find it

Comment: @mamu It's specific to the interactive shell (fsi). It terminates the input and makes it be evaluated. You can remove them.

Comment: Note that you can also do a `[ for (first, _, _) in lst do yield first ]` which is the same as seq syntax but gives a list straight away

Comment: Or even shorter using a bit of syntactic sugar: you can replace a single `do yield x` by `-> x` like this: `[for (first,_,_) in lst -> first]`

Answer (score 8):

You just need a List.map with a 'project' function:

```
let newList = List.map (fun (x, _, _) -> x) orgList
```

The `List.map` takes a function and a list and applies the function to each item in the list. The `(fun (x, _, _) -> x)` unpacks the tuple and returns the first item.

HTH,
Rob

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted 2/3 of the values you could also do this:

```
let newList = oldList |> List.collect ( fun (a,b,_) -> [a;b])
```

Answer (score -3):

The builtin function `fst` extracts the first element of a tuple, so you can just map `fst` over the list:

```
lst |> List.map fst

(* 'a*'b*'c list -> 'a list *)
```